# New Google Apps Script Editor - Additional Bound Projects?

Tags: google-apps-script, ide

In the legacy Google Apps Script Editor, you could easily create additional Projects that were bound to the parent Sheet / Doc / Slide, under File -> New -> Project.

In the new Google Apps Script Editor, it's easy to add new Files to the existing Project.  But I haven't seen a way to create whole new Projects, that are bound to the parent container.

I've read a number of articles talking about the new editor.  And for the most part, I agree that it's a great step forward (finally - code blocks!).  It's a shame that Find only looks in the active file now, whereas it used to look across all files in the project, but I can get over that.  But nothing I've read indicates how to create additional Project bound to the container.  Is this feature gone, or am I just missing it somewhere?

Comment: Consider creating a feature request/bug report in the issuetracker. See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for more details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google has removed the function to create another bound project directly from the new editor, but you can make a clone of the existing bound project by going to the `Overview` menu and selecting `Make a Copy`.

The new project will also be bound to the container.

**Original:**
[image]

**Copy:**
[image]

Comment: thank you for that ! I didn't think about it and was really wondering how to do... Actually, the new environment is IMHO quite less user frendly ;)